# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 4D6F7374

Tags: serialization, java-io

The Java code is

```
        ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("src/Stringdata.txt"));    
        String s=(String)ois.readObject();
        System.out.println(s.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

here am getting java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 4D6F7374 this error please help me

Answer (score 4):

[An ObjectInputStream deserializes primitive data and objects previously written using an ObjectOutputStream.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html)  `src/Stringdata.txt` is probably not a file of serialized objects previously written using an ObjectOutputStream.  You probably want to use [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) instead

Answer (score 0):

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 4D6F7374
```

4D6F7374 is "Most".

This is not a file of serialized objects. It is a text file. Read it with `BufferedReader.readLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is:
Server send/receive data using DataOutputStream/DataInputStream and you are trying to read it in the client side using ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream

Just make sure Server/Client sockets are reading/writing using the same input/output stream types.

Khalil.