# Deserializing objects using a pointer

Tags: java, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize the 9 objects of the class `Planet` which are stored on the `planetobject.txt` file: [image]

But it gives me error that says:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: Planet; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -1020679419761445431, local class serialVersionUID = -3074022091766650572
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at LA7ex5a.main(LA7ex5a.java:20)
```

Here is the expected output (which I am not getting):

```
Mercury 57910000.0  4880.0  3.30e23
Venus   108200000.0 12103.6 4.869e24
Earth   149600000.0 12756.3 5.972e24 
Mars    227940000.0     6794.0  6.4219e23
Jupitor 778330000.0 142984  1.900e27 
Saturn  1429400000.0    120536  5.68e26 
Uranus  2870990000.0    51118.0 8.683e25
Neptune 4504000000.0    49532.0 1.0247e26 
Pluto   5913520000.0    2274.0  1.27e22
```

I would appreciate it if someone could guide me what the problem is.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class LA7ex5a {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectInputStream objectinput = null;
        Planet [] planet = null;
        int i=0;
        try {
            objectinput = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/user/workspace/LA7ex5a/src/planetobject.txt"));

            planet = (Planet[])objectinput.readObject();
            planet = (Planet[])objectinput.readObject();
            while (i<0) {
                planet[i].print();
                i++;
            }
            objectinput.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Planet implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private double orbit, diameter, mass;

    public Planet(String name, double orbit, double diameter, double mass) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.orbit = orbit;
        this.diameter = diameter;
        this.mass = mass;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(name+" "+orbit+" "+diameter+" "+mass);   
    }

}
```

Comment: As stated in the exception message, your class `Planet` **does not** correspond to the one that has been serialized.

Comment: But I serialized the same class. I don't understand how to fix it.

Comment: It's a double because I serialized the objects first, now I am trying to deserialize them.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare serialVersionUID in your class, as if you don't declare it explicitly then at compile time it gets generated automatically. So if you have serialzied the object before and done some changes in class then serialVersionUID may have been changed.

And for De-serialization of a class serialVersionUID of class and the serialized object should match to get a object instance from serialized object.

add the following in you Planet class

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1020679419761445431L;
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. give me this:
java.io.InvalidClassException: Planet; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -1020679419761445431, local class serialVersionUID = 1
 at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
 at LA7ex5a.main(LA7ex5a.java:21)

Comment: it will not work as your serialized object contains different serialVersionUID, I have updated my answer try that.

Comment: but this UID is out of range.

Comment: Yes i figured that out, but now the problem comes in the reading object.

Comment: My suggestion will be you should declare the new serialVersionUID , and serialize a new object and De-serialized it. As you should have declared serialVersionUID before serializing the object.

Comment: Better use InputStreamReader your text might not be an serialized object using ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709017/java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-stream-header-4d6f7374

Answer (score 0):

try this :

First before serialization and deserialization you need to declare

```
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

as your class implements Serializable interface
in your Plannet class. and then you can read as:

```
     objectinput = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(
                "C:/Users/user/workspace/LA7ex5a/src/planetobject.txt"));
        planet = (Plannet[])objectinput.readObject();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(planet));
        objectinput.close();
```

Comment: gives me this:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Planet cannot be cast to [LPlanet;
 at LA7ex5a.main(LA7ex5a.java:19)

Comment: when you serialized Plannet Object. Have you serialize separate object or array of object..?

Comment: let me send you the link to the code how I serialized it:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vos7uqasvyhw6o/serialize.txt

Comment: I did that but then I get an error in this line :
 planet = (Planet[])objectinput.readObject();

IT says:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Planet cannot be cast to [LPlanet;
 at LA7ex5b.main(LA7ex5b.java:17)

Comment: yes because you saved Plannet object one by one not an array of Plannet. so you get by objectinput.readObject() only single object of Plannet not an array that's why it's giving ClassCastException.

Comment: how do I fix it then?

Comment: do one thing..I got your file in that the while loop you have line as output.writeObject(p[i]); place that line out of while loop as  output.writeObject(p); means save array of Plannet. so you could get an array Of Plannet..